# Comparison doesn't yield result in iOS

Tags: ios, int, nsmutablearray, comparison

I am trying to compare two items' id and it's never being true though its actually meets te=he expected condition.

```
-(int) calculateScore : (int) itemId{

   NSLog(@"Item id count..:: %d", vmScore.itemIdArray.count);
   for(int i=0; i<vmScore.itemIdArray.count; i++){

       if(itemId == vmScore.itemIdArray[i]){
          score += 10;
      }
    }

   return score;
}
```

itemIdArray is an array of integer and itemId is fetched from - SafetyDeviceIdArray[i], again a NSMutable array property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
if (itemId == [vmScore.itemIdArray[i] intValue]) {
 score += 10;
}
```

instead of

```
if (itemId == vmScore.itemIdArray[i]) {
 score += 10;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Following code to fulfill your requirement.

-(int) calculateScore : (int) itemId{

```
   NSLog(@"Item id count..:: %d", vmScore.itemIdArray.count);
   for(int i=0; i<vmScore.itemIdArray.count; i++){

       if(itemId == [vmScore.itemIdArray[i] intValue]){
         // Your code goes here 
         score += 10;
      }
    }

   return score;
}
```